# Is it possible to make an android app that uses cellular data without a SIM?

Tags: android

My background is more in Mechatronics/Robotics, so I'm very new to android app development. Basically I'd like to use an Android phone to control two robotic systems that will need to talk to each other over a distance of around 2-3km. I'd like to the cellular transceivers on the phone to achieve this, without needing to connect to the mobile network as they should be within range. Essentially I want to turn the phones into glorified walkie-talkies.

I've done a bit of research, but I've only found ways to use the cellular function through pre-built APIs that use the network, thus needing a SIM card. Is there any way to access the transceiver directly and use it to communicate with a custom protocol? Would this require a custom ROM/kernel modifications?

Comment: On Android there is the Radio Interface Layer (RIL) but as far as I know you need root to access this interface. Everything below this layer is proprietary and closed-source (and device dependent). Note that the mobile network operators have an exclusive license to use their frequencies. Using those frequencies without permission may end up serious punishments. If you want to connect two devices via cellular talk to your MNO for an IoT/data plan or use other long-range radio hardware.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I did a bit of research into it and it seems more logical to just have an IoT data plan rather than trying to hack the phone. A bit more expensive but oh well :D